# Aws lambda vs aws batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I am currently working on a project where I need to merge two significantly large csv files into one(both are a few hundred MBs). I am fairly new to aws. I am aware of memory allocation and execution time limitations of lambda. Other than that are there any advantages of using batch jobs over lambda for this project? Is there any other aws component which more suitable for this task? Either lambda or batch job will be triggered inside a step function using a sns notification.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function has some limitations:

- Execute time: 15 mins
- RAM: 3G
- disk space `/tmp` only 500mb <= difficult to store any file large than this number on lambda

The good point is cheap and fast boot up

I suggest you use the ECS (Both Fargate and Container are good)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Python function in Lambda that writes to S3 with boto3.